# Using Microsoft adaptive cards in Java

Tags: java, azure, botframework

I'm trying to implement a chat bot in Java utilizing adaptive cards, much like the C# sample [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-teams-catering/csharp).

I can get the bot to display a card in Teams, but I am unable to process any responses, as I always get this exception:

```
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715171392Z: [INFO]  

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.bot.builder.ActivityHandler$InvokeResponseException
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715176693Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715182093Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715186993Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715191793Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.ActivityHandler.onTurn(ActivityHandler.java:105) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715196594Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.MiddlewareSet.receiveActivityInternal(MiddlewareSet.java:99) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715201494Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.MiddlewareSet.lambda$receiveActivityInternal$1(MiddlewareSet.java:110) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715206394Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.BotFrameworkAdapter$TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.onTurn(BotFrameworkAdapter.java:1430) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715211294Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.MiddlewareSet.receiveActivityInternal(MiddlewareSet.java:109) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715216095Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.MiddlewareSet.receiveActivityInternal(MiddlewareSet.java:74) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715220795Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.MiddlewareSet.receiveActivityWithStatus(MiddlewareSet.java:67) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715225395Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.BotAdapter.runPipeline(BotAdapter.java:206) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715243796Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.lambda$processActivity$2(BotFrameworkAdapter.java:478) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715248396Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715252696Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715256997Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(BotFrameworkAdapter.java:476) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715261997Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.lambda$processActivity$1(BotFrameworkAdapter.java:433) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715266297Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715270397Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715274597Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(BotFrameworkAdapter.java:433) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715278798Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.integration.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.processIncomingActivity(BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.java:102) ~[bot-integration-core-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715283098Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.integration.spring.BotController.incoming(BotController.java:84) ~[bot-integration-spring-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715287298Z: [INFO]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715291498Z: [INFO]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715295699Z: [INFO]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715299799Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715303799Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715308199Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715312499Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715317000Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715321400Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715325800Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715330300Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715338401Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715342801Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715347001Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715351101Z: [INFO]      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715355202Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715359702Z: [INFO]      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715364102Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715368302Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.715372902Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719456008Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719463708Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719468709Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719473209Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719477709Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719482209Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719497610Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719502910Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719507111Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719511411Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719515611Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719529412Z: [INFO]      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719533812Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719538012Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719542212Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719546413Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719550513Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719554813Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719559013Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719563113Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719567314Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719572214Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719576414Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719580514Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719584714Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719588815Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719593015Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719597015Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719601115Z: [INFO]      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719605216Z: [INFO]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719609216Z: [INFO]  Caused by: com.microsoft.bot.builder.ActivityHandler$InvokeResponseException: null
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719613216Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.ActivityHandler.getAdaptiveCardInvokeValue(ActivityHandler.java:712) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719621116Z: [INFO]      at com.microsoft.bot.builder.ActivityHandler.onInvokeActivity(ActivityHandler.java:408) ~[bot-builder-4.14.0.jar!/:4.14.0]
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719625517Z: [INFO]      ... 68 common frames omitted
2021-11-23T05:32:35.719629517Z: [INFO]
```

I've narrowed the issue down to this code in the `com.microsoft.bot.builder.ActivityHandler` class:

```
Object obj = activity.getValue();
JsonNode node = null;
if (obj instanceof JsonNode) {
  node = (JsonNode) obj;
} else {
  AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse response = createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
      HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "BadRequest", "Value property instanceof not properly formed");
  throw new InvokeResponseException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, response);
}
```

From this code I can see that a `InvokeResponseException` will be thrown if the `activity.getValue()` object is not an instance of `JsonNode`.

I went so far as to pull this code out into my own class and logged out the actual object type that was being returned:

```
Object obj = activity.getValue();
JsonNode node = null;
LOGGER.error("obj type: " + obj.getClass().getName());
if (obj instanceof JsonNode) {
  node = (JsonNode) obj;
} else {
  AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse response = createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
      HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "BadRequest", "Value property instanceof not properly formed");
  throw new InvokeResponseException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, response);
}
```

The actual object type is `java.util.LinkedHashMap`.

So what is the solution here? Is there a configuration option that changes how the activity responses are deserialized by a standard chat bot project? I was basing my code off the sample project created with Yeoman `yo botbuilder-java -T "echo"` described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=java%2Cvs).

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be a bug with the Java Bot Framework SDK, but in the mean time I have worked around the problem with an intermediate class that accepts a Map from `activity.getValue()` (see the line `invokeValue = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, AdaptiveCardInvokeValue.class);`):

```
package com.matthewcasperson;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.microsoft.bot.builder.ActivityHandler;
import com.microsoft.bot.builder.InvokeResponse;
import com.microsoft.bot.builder.TurnContext;
import com.microsoft.bot.connector.Async;
import com.microsoft.bot.schema.Activity;
import com.microsoft.bot.schema.AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse;
import com.microsoft.bot.schema.AdaptiveCardInvokeValue;
import com.microsoft.bot.schema.Serialization;
import com.microsoft.bot.schema.SignInConstants;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FixedActivityHandler extends ActivityHandler {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CateringBot.class);

  @Override
  protected CompletableFuture<InvokeResponse> onInvokeActivity(TurnContext turnContext) {
    if (StringUtils.equals(turnContext.getActivity().getName(), "adaptiveCard/action")) {
      AdaptiveCardInvokeValue invokeValue = null;
      try {
        invokeValue = getAdaptiveCardInvokeValue(turnContext.getActivity());
      } catch (InvokeResponseException e) {
        return Async.completeExceptionally(e);
      }
      return onAdaptiveCardInvoke(turnContext, invokeValue).thenApply(result -> createInvokeResponse(result));
    }

    if (
        StringUtils.equals(
            turnContext.getActivity().getName(), SignInConstants.VERIFY_STATE_OPERATION_NAME
        ) || StringUtils.equals(
            turnContext.getActivity().getName(), SignInConstants.TOKEN_EXCHANGE_OPERATION_NAME
        )
    ) {
      return onSignInInvoke(turnContext).thenApply(aVoid -> createInvokeResponse(null))
          .exceptionally(ex -> {
            if (
                ex instanceof CompletionException
                    && ex.getCause() instanceof InvokeResponseException
            ) {
              InvokeResponseException ire = (InvokeResponseException) ex.getCause();
              return new InvokeResponse(500, "");
            } else if (ex instanceof InvokeResponseException) {
              InvokeResponseException ire = (InvokeResponseException) ex;
              return new InvokeResponse(500, "");
            }
            return new InvokeResponse(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR, null);
          });
    }

    CompletableFuture<InvokeResponse> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    result.complete(new InvokeResponse(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, null));
    return result;
  }

  private AdaptiveCardInvokeValue getAdaptiveCardInvokeValue(Activity activity) throws InvokeResponseException {
    if (activity.getValue() == null) {
      AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse response = createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
          HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "BadRequest", "Missing value property");
      throw new InvokeResponseException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, response);
    }

    /*
      The original code required activity.getValue() to be a JsonNode. It is in fact a
      LinkedHashMap, so this change allows the response to proceed.
     */
    Object obj = activity.getValue();
    AdaptiveCardInvokeValue invokeValue = null;
    if (obj instanceof JsonNode) {
      invokeValue = Serialization.treeToValue((JsonNode) obj, AdaptiveCardInvokeValue.class);
    } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
      final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
      invokeValue = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, AdaptiveCardInvokeValue.class);
    } else {
      AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse response = createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
          HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "BadRequest", "Value property instanceof not properly formed");
      throw new InvokeResponseException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, response);
    }
    /*
      End of changes
     */

    if (invokeValue == null) {
      AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse response = createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
          HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "BadRequest", "Value property instanceof not properly formed");
      throw new InvokeResponseException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, response);
    }

    if (invokeValue.getAction() == null) {
      AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse response = createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
          HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "BadRequest", "Missing action property");
      throw new InvokeResponseException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, response);
    }

    if (!invokeValue.getAction().getType().equals("Action.Execute")) {
      AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse response = createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
          HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "NotSupported",
          String.format("The action '%s'is not supported.", invokeValue.getAction().getType()));
      throw new InvokeResponseException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, response);
    }

    return invokeValue;
  }

  private AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse createAdaptiveCardInvokeErrorResponse(
      Integer statusCode,
      String code,
      String message
  ) {
    AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse adaptiveCardInvokeResponse = new AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse();
    adaptiveCardInvokeResponse.setStatusCode(statusCode);
    adaptiveCardInvokeResponse.setType("application/vnd.getmicrosoft().error");
    com.microsoft.bot.schema.Error error = new com.microsoft.bot.schema.Error();
    error.setCode(code);
    error.setMessage(message);
    adaptiveCardInvokeResponse.setValue(error);
    return adaptiveCardInvokeResponse;
  }
}
```